Connecting Sourcetree to a virtual unix box
I'm running sourcetree on a mac, but all of the work is being done on a virtual unix box that I access via ssh from terminal. How do I get sourcetree on my mac to connect to the repo on the unix box?

can someone at least comment to explain the close votes? Is there a better board for this to be on? Is it already answered somewhere I missed?

I am not sure how you set up the virtual unix box but I can give you some general advice.
I remotely work on my git server but I do computer to computer, but the idea is the same.
Run git remote -v to get the SSH URL of the repository from the git folder on the virtual box.
Then, Open SourceTree on your Mac, click on the "Remote" menu and select "Add", choose "Add from URL" option, paste the SSH URL of your Git repo.
Go to "SourceTree" > "Preferences" > "Authentication" if you need to do authentication.
